# DynamoDB PartiQL select statement with IN operator on both partition key and sort key - How RCU is calculated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, partiql

**use case:**
Need to retrieve data from Dynamodb for multiple pk(PartitionKey)+sk(SortKey) combination. So leveraging the IN operator in partiql on both pk and sk.

I did small poc on how much RCU is getting consumed for 2 types of partiql pattern.

- **Pattern 1**: RCU consumed = 5, Returned item count = 4. For the query:

SELECT * from "test" where pk IN ['12185','05405','14222'] and sk IN ['CELL_ID:101','CAM_ID:12185','CAM_ID:05405','CAM_ID:14222','CAM_ID:14223'];

- **Pattern 2**: RCU consumed = 1.5 , Returned item count = 30. For the query:

SELECT * from "test" where pk IN ['12185','05405','14222'];

**Question** -

1. How RCU is getting calculated for these two partiQL patterns?

The answer to this question will help me up in designing the query. If IN operator on both pk and sk is bad idea, i will stick with In operator only on pk and do the sk filtering at the application side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using PartiQL you need to understand how it converts to the lower level API.

```
SELECT * from "test" 
where pk IN ['12185','05405','14222'] 
and sk IN ['CELL_ID:101','CAM_ID:12185','CAM_ID:05405','CAM_ID:14222','CAM_ID:14223'];
```

Here you are using 3 partition keys, but 5 sort keys which will result in 10 operations being executed. PartiQL backend will only allow 10 internal `GetItem` requests before you need to paginate, and as your requests are eventually consistent each of the consumes 0.5 RCU:

10 * 0.5 = 5RCU consumed

```
SELECT * from "test" where pk IN ['12185','05405','14222'];
```

This will result in 3 `Query` operations, each of the queries will be rounded up to the nearest 4KB.

3 * 0.5  = 1.5 RCU consumed

Comment: is there any documentation on partiql's 10 GetItem limitation?

Comment: Its not a limitation, you just need to paginate. The query which you are using is not optimal, and with all non-optimal queries you should include pagination. You can tell that the request is not complete as it will return a `NextToken` in the response telling you there are more items to retrieve.

Comment: Agree that the query is not optimal here. Guess for my use case, batchGetItem suits more than the partiql IN operator.